# How to find the shortest simple closed curve between two parallel simple closed curves?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, curves

Here is a problem that I have been stuck with:

**Given a simple closed curve $\alpha _1$, the curve parallel to it $\alpha _2$ and a distance $ε$ between any two points with common normal (green on the picture).**

**Find the shortest simple closed curve which lies between the parallel curves (red on the picture).**

[see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysjJ4.png)

I would be grateful for any advice. There are papers around with a discrete algorithm solution, but I'm interested only in an analytic solution.